# Gas displayed on "Remix"

Tags: remix, gas, opcode

Is Gas displayed on "Remix" at function execution the same as when executed on the main net?

I'm using the Javascript VM as the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be. The gas cost relates to the size of the contract to deploy and the OPCODES executed by functions in the course of a given transaction. Those should be same in either case.

A departure could be due to conditional logic where the initial conditions are different. For example `if(block.number > 1000000) { // do conditional things }`.

Hope it helps.